# converting json to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
tweets_filename = 'fetched_tweets.json'
tweets_file = open(tweets_filename, "r")
tweets_data=[]
df=pd.DataFrame();
for line in tweets_file:
      tweet = json.loads(line)
      tweets_data.append(tweet)
      df['created_at'] = map(lambda tweet: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(tweet['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')), tweets_data)
      df['user'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweets_data)
df.to_csv('fetched_df.csv')
```

The csv file shows only one row and the entries are shown as

```
                       created_at                            user
0  map object at 0x7f93cba73b00>      map object at 0x7f93cba73630>
```

The `fetched_tweets.json` file was created using the code

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):    
    def on_data(self, data):    
        with open('fetched_tweets.json','a') as tf:    
            tf.write(data)    
        return True    
    def on_error(self, status):    
        print (status)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    #This handles Twitter authetification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)
    stream.filter(track=['fakenews'])
```

how to print data from dataframe where it shows map to object and how to get all the rows?

Comment: Please, next time, format you code according to the rules (all code lines should begin with 4 spaces, this can be done with `Alt+K`). For this post I did it for you. Also, it is much better to provide a snippet of your original data file instead of code that generated it: I really can't recreate this data file with the code without serious efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want

```
for line in tweets_file:
      tweet = json.loads(line)
      tweets_data.append(tweet)

# decrease indent here, we don't want
# the following lines to be in the loop

df['created_at'] = list(map(lambda tweet: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(tweet['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')), tweets_data))
df['user'] = list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweets_data))
```

As `map` is generator in Python 3, you have to explicitly convert it to `list` to assign to pandas column.